# SQL Server DB recovery

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation when restoring a database from full backup. The restore operation ran for 2 hours & failed with an error 9002(In-sufficient log space) & the database went to suspect mode.

Allocating extra space to drive would resolve my issue? or need to make any changes in back up plan?

How do we need to troubleshoot this issue?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to over come this.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (pun intended) yes. The puzzling thing to me is that restore should do this check before actually *doing* the restore. Either way, you can check the size of the files that you need by issuing the following:

```
restore filelistonly from disk = 'yourBackupFile.bak'
```

This will give you a list of the physical files that were present when the backup was taken, how big they were at the time (and by extension how big they'll be when you restore them), and where they'll be restored to. You can affect the latter by issuing `WITH MOVE` clauses in the restore.